# How to copy/package Power App

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a site template with few lists that we use frequently to create sites for different departments. We have created a Power App for one of the lists in this site and want to have this as part of template.

We tried and power app is not getting copied with the site/list template. Is there any way to package the power app so that for lists created with same template we can re-use the work done to create the power app?